# SPM empty is module

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

I just made a SPM module for iOS, fixed error from `xcodebuild` output and runned some tests - it's just fine.

But when i added this SPM into a project - my classes, functions, and constants defined in modelue, weren't in module at all! By the way, entire module is empty, except few imports, that i wasn't placing there.

My **Package.swift**:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.3
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "BotComputer",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v14),],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "BotComputer",
            targets: ["BotComputer"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "BotComputer",
            dependencies: []
        ),
        .testTarget(
            name: "BotComputerTests",
            dependencies: ["BotComputer"]),
    ]
)
```

... And the module after import contains just this (*cmd+click on **import MyModule** -> jump to definition*):

```
import class Foundation.Bundle
import MetalKit
import SwiftOnoneSupport
```

Well, i'm stuck.

Comment: please check if the classes, functions, and constants  have the correct access modifier like public.
Also, please check if all the changes are on the version control.

Answer (score 1):

Yea, like @francisco.garcia said - i've got no access modifiers at all, but `public` made all the stuff. Thanx a lot!
Not kinda obvious thing...